# Adding a proxy to a networking app without changing code possible?

Tags: java, proxy

I want to use a Java application, which is not written by me and also not maintained anymore, meaning I can't just go to the author and ask for a new feature. What options do I have to add proxy capabalities. Is it possible to add some shell arguments? Is it manageable work to add the binary code for the proxy directly into the `.class` file? Could I write my own class, import the stuff from the `.class` files and overwrite the network functionality?

Comment: There are plenty of Java decompilers out there. But I don't know how legal that is and if the author approves this.

Comment: yep, there was typo. Don't forget that https proxy configuration is separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=IP_address -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -jar App.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to replace a class with your own implementation by creating a class with the same name/package and placing it earlier in the classpath so it takes precedence. However you cannot break binary compatibility if this class is used by other parts of the code.

There are also instrumentation APIs available to modify classes as they are loaded. See the [Instrumentation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

Comment: I `accepted` the easiest solution. Your's is also interesting, though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own source file that references the compiled `.class`, then in your file try doing this:

```
java.util.Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost", PROXY_HOST);
systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort", PROXY_PORT);
```

I think that should work.

Comment: Please explain the downvote?  I've used this in a similar situation and it worked for me.